# How do I use the L switch with a variable name?

Tags: c++, unicode

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::string t_prefix = "\u2554";
    std::string t_middle = "";
    std::string t_suffix = "\u2557\n\u2551";
    int max_message_length = 33;

    for (int i = t_middle.length(); i < max_message_length; i++) {

        t_middle = "\u2550" + t_middle;

    }
    std::string complete_message = t_prefix + t_middle + t_suffix;


    std::wcout << L"\u2554" << t_middle.c_str() << L"\u2557\n\u2551";
    
    std::wcout << complete_message.c_str();
    //std::wcout << L"\u2554\n";

}
```

The first wout line prints the first and last part right, the middle section prints out garbage because it does not have the L in it. (How do I use the L with a variable?)
The second wout line combines the prefix, message, and suffix prints out garbage since it needs the L switch to print properly? I find a million of examples of how to do it with straight hard coded text L"\u2554\u2550\u2550" ect ect but I wanted the program to be a little more flexible so the game boarder could be wider if so set.

Comment: You could using `std::wstring` (with `L"blah"` literals) instead of `std::string`.  I tend to go the UTF-8 everywhere route, but your code is already going with `_O_U16TEXT`.  Otherwise you'll need a `std::string` to `std::wstring` conversion when outputting the strings.

Comment: I need to know how to use the L with a variable. the L"blah" works fine if I want to hard code 33 of my Unicode characters in between "" and L variable_name throws an error unknow L

Comment: Do you mean like:  `std::wstring t_suffix = L"\u2557\n\u2551";` ?

Comment: No I mean I need to know how to get the L in this statement so it do not throw an error and prints out the characters correctly std::wcout << complete_message.c_str();

Comment: Change it to: `std::wstring complete_message = t_prefix + t_middle + t_suffix;` (and also change the other three variables to `std::wstring`), and then `std::wcout << complete_message;`

Comment: I been trying everything you said and the program will not compile. Run the code and see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and do what I need it to do at least for windows:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);

   std::wstring t_prefix { L'\u2554' };
   std::wstring t_suffix { L"\u2557\n\u2551" };

   std::wstring t_middle;

   const size_t max_message_length { 33 };

   for (size_t i { t_middle.size() }; i < max_message_length; ++i)
   {
      t_middle += L'\u2550';
   }

   std::wstring complete_message { t_prefix + t_middle + t_suffix };

   std::wcout << complete_message << '\n';
}
```

and this is suppose to work on linux:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string t_prefix = "╔";
    std::string t_middle;
    std::string t_suffix = "╗\n║";
    int max_message_length = 33;

    for (int i = t_middle.size(); i < max_message_length; ++i)
        t_middle = "═" + t_middle;

    std::string complete_message = t_prefix + t_middle + t_suffix;
    std::cout << complete_message << '\n';
}
```